# why is the bias of an AR(1) model converging towards 0 for $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, bias, autoregressive

could someone please explain to me why the statement at the end is true?

The estimator of $\alpha$ in an AR(1) process is biased, meaning:
$E[\hat{\alpha} ]\neq \alpha$ this is because $E[\hat{\alpha}]= \alpha + E[\frac{\sum w_tx_{t-1}}{\sum x_{t-1}^2}].$

Proving this, was not a problem for me however I fail to see why $E[\frac{\sum w_tx_{t-1}}{\sum x_{t-1}^2}]$ is converging to 0, for $n\to \infty $.